# PHP return value

Tags: php, object

If a static method returns an object .. can I in one line get one of the objects attributes?
Something like this but in a single line :

```
$obj = Parser::GetFirstItem();
$strTitle = $obj->Title;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you actually tried it?

```
$strTitle = Parser::GetFirstItem()->Title;
```

That should work, provided you're using PHP5 and not still stuck on PHP4.

[Here's a link to an article about it](http://www.talkphp.com/advanced-php-programming/1163-php5-method-chaining.html).

Answer (score 3):

Sure. Just try it out:

```
$strTitle = Parser::GetFirstItem()->Title;
```

Not entirely sure when this was introduced. 5? 5.1? 5.2? Will have to check.

**Update:** Seems to have been a PHP 5 feature from the start.

Comment: that'll be $strTitle = ... not $obj.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your `GetFirstItem` method should returns an object. Only virtual (not static methods) can do this:

```
return $this;
```

Comment: Using `return self;` in a static function returns an `E_NOTICE` that `self` is an undefined constant, assumes you meant `'self'`, and returns a string. (Note: PHP 5.3.2). If you want an object of the class that has the static function, then you should use `return new self();`